# Mastermind game, Choosing what colour to guess

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I am trying to create a mastermind game within python

I have tried to use a text box input to get the choice of colour and have an array backed grid as my grid.
When I type in a colour for example 'blue' the whole grid turns blue whereas I would like it to store the input and let the user choose which squares in the grid to turn blue

Any help is appreciated

```
while not done:
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:


        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


        column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
        row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)



        print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if input_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            active = True
        else:
            active = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if active == True:
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                user_text = user_text[0:-1]
            else:
                user_text += event.unicode
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            user_text = user_text
            print(user_text)

if active:
    color = color_active
else:
    color=color_passive
pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,input_rect,2)
text_surface= base_font.render(user_text,True,(255,255,255))
screen.blit(text_surface, (input_rect.x +5, input_rect.y + 5))

#input_rect.w = max(20, text_surface.get_width() + 10)

for row in range(8):
    for column in range(4):
        color = WHITE
        if user_text == 'blue':
            print (grid)
            grid[row][column] = 2
            color = BLUE
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                              (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                              WIDTH,
                              HEIGHT])

        if user_text == 'green':
            grid[row][column] = 1
            color = GREEN
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                         color,
                         [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                          (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                          WIDTH,
                          HEIGHT])
```

[The result after typing 'blue'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFeLX.png)

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: The code turns the whole grid blue, instead of holding the input and letting user choose which square to turn blue, by clicking on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Changing block color**

Judging from your code, you haven't individually stored the information for each block. You need to do this since each block will have different features(colour). It would really help to have some kind of a data structure to keep store each block information. But for now just store the colours in an array as.

```
  colors = [(0, 0, 0) for i in range(array_width * array_height)]
```

**Selecting blocks**

Store a bunch of bools to indicate if the selected block is active.

```
  blocks = [False for i in range(array_width * array_height)]
```

Then you can loop over this array every frame and set the ones that have been clicked to `True` (or toggle it, which is better in my personal opinion).

```
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

    #iterate through the 2d array
    for i in range(array_width):
        for j in range(array_height):

            column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
            row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)

            blocks[row * array_width + column] = not blocks[row * array_width + column] #toggle
            #convert 2d array index to 1d array at mouse position and set the bool at that index to True
            #blocks[row * array_width + column] = True
```

Then iterate over the blocks and set the color.

```
array_width = 4
array_height = 8
for row in range(array_width):
    for column in range(array_height):

        #CHECK IF BLOCK SHOULD BE CHANGED
        if blocks[column * array_width + row]:
            if user_text == 'blue':
                colors[column * array_height + row] = (0, 0, 255)
```

**Drawing blocks**

Now this also means that you have to do the drawing in a different loop (even in your code in the question there is also no need to write draw rect call twice, just un-indent the second one).

```
for row in range(array_width):
    for column in range(array_height):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                                     #GET THE COLOR AT THAT INDEX
                                     colors[column * array_width + row],
                                     [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                                      (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                                      WIDTH,
                                      HEIGHT])
```

Then you could also set all the blocks back to false after the user enters blue presses enter key, just for convenience.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about this, but when i use the code it says                                         
blocks[row * array_height + column] = not blocks[row * array_height + column]  # toggle
IndexError: list index out of range  Thanks again

Comment: @LukeWilliams I am not sure since I don't have access to your code or I misunderstood the intent of your original code. The general rule to convert from 2d to 1d array is `y * width + x`. So just make sure that its `blocks[y-coordinate * width_of_the_array + x_coordinate]`.

Comment: Try swapping `array_height` with `array_width` and make sure `column` represents the `y` coordinate and `row` represents the `x` coordinate

Comment: Ok, i might have under explained sorry about that, I can see the problem though. The code is taking the co ordinates of the text box when it is clicked, so that is making the index out of range. Any possible workaround? Thanks. Also i may just have the code muddled a bit so it could just be the fact that i have layed out the code incorrectly

Comment: Coordinates of text box should not affect the array as they are completely different. I can't tell without looking at your code. It would be better to ask a new question with your code and problem explained properly.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, i will do that